# How to delete initial field value when user clicks on respective box?

Tags: html, django, events, onclick

I want to know if its possible writing some code which will delete an initial value from a form when the user clicks on the corresponding form (described in the following example)?

```
class example(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    descr = forms.CharField(initial='Please insert a relevant description ...')
```

I dont want to use the help_text attribute.

PS: For a better understanding I could make an analogy with java onclick event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use HTML5's placeholder attribute directly from Django:

```
descr = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'placeholder': 'Please insert a relevant description ...'}))
```

The unique constraint is that it is not yet supported by Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a webservice you'll have to use javascript. If you use jQuery, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_descr').one('click', function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for the backend part, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101258/how-do-i-add-a-placeholder-on-a-charfield-in-django/4101282#4101282). For the frontend, you may wish to add a html5 shiv to get placeholders in legacy browsers