# Django - Registration form default value of fields

Tags: django, django-registration, user-registration

I'm using django django register form so my Registe form looks like this

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password',)
        widgets = {
           'password': forms.PasswordInput()
        }
```

but when I go to the registration page some of fields are already fill in with values I used to log in to my superuser I would like to make them empty or have some default value like something@somthing.com but I have no idea how can I do that.
I'm using Django 1.7 and Python 2.7

I try to log in with different user and I realased that in registration form is password I used the last time, so it not the same ale the time but it's the last remebered password.

I clean history and when website don't remeber any password then form looks like I want, placeholder works etc.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101258/how-do-i-add-a-placeholder-on-a-charfield-in-django

Comment: Do you have a logout function? If so please post it. Also, when you changed the `models.py` and `forms.py` did you stop the server, sync the database, and restart the server?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than defining it in the `Meta` class, try defining it your form definition like so:

```
email = forms.EmailField(label='email', 
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'example@domain.com'}))
```

Or you could do this in jQuery like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id_username").attr('placeholder', '{{form.username.label}}');
        $("#id_email").attr('placeholder', '{{form.email.label}}');
    });
</script>
```

And then define your `label='example@domain.com'`.

## Edit

You could try reinitializing an empty form after your user logs in like so:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    rf = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if rf.is_valid():
        # This reinitializes an empty form before rendering a response
        rf = LoginForm()
        return render_to_response(...)
```

Comment: I'm not using input in template. I'm using '{{ form.as_p }}'.

Comment: missing forms. before EmailInput wasn't the problem, I've added it before and still nothing

Comment: See my edit if the email is a `TextInput` and an alternative method in jQuery.

Comment: look at my last update to question (two last lines).

Comment: still nothing! 
I hate Django so much. It's my first project and I hope it's also the last one.

Comment: Django is a powerful framework that has a moderately steep learning curve. Stick with it and you'll learn to enjoy using it. See my most recent edit.

Comment: What if I don't have any Login Form, I'm using django.contrib.auth.views.login so I can't do what you wrote. I was thinking about forbide the website to remeber passwords but I have no idea if I can do this and how.

Comment: Do you have a `logout` function? And if so, what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Just to use placeholder for that

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        'email': EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'something@something.com'}),
    }
```

Comment: @Meii I will ask you one more question ? what is the error you are getting when you follow my method ? you are just simply telling still nothing can't help us to figure out what mistake you are doing out ther

Comment: there is no error, but register form is fill in with data which was last save durning the log in for example I used username 'lol' and in register form in field email (yes, email not username) I've got 'lol'. It looks like placeholder is overwrite by that data but I don't know why.

Comment: @Meii do you have `locals()` in your view. May be that will cause the override and once you clear your current session and cookie and restart the server. do freshly let's see what's comming ...

Comment: I don't have locals()

Comment: I haven't got. My project is very primitive cause it's my first project in python.

Comment: I will but I'd know anything about python so I don't believe I will find it, especialy I've got about six hours to finish it.

Comment: I can post you a pice of code which you want to see