# Can i edit the tags from a Model field?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

```
myapp/models.py
class BookDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book_language = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='English')
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

myapp/views.py

```
class BookDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookDetails
        fields = ('book_language', 'book_title', 'book_author',)
```

so the html generated is :

```
<tr><th><label for="id_book_language">Book language:</label></th><td><input id="id_book_language" maxlength="10" name="book_language" type="text" value="English" required /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_book_title">Book title:</label></th><td><input id="id_book_title" maxlength="100" name="book_title" type="text" required /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_book_author">Book author:</label></th><td><input id="id_book_author" maxlength="100" name="book_author" type="text" required /></td></tr>
```

desired HTML

```
<tr><th></th><td><input id="id_book_language" maxlength="10" name="book_language" type="text" value="English" placeholder='language'required /></td></tr>
<tr><th></th><td><input id="id_book_title" maxlength="100" name="book_title" type="text" placeholder='title' required /></td></tr>
<tr><th></th><td><input id="id_book_author" maxlength="100" name="book_author" type="text" placeholder='Author' required /></td></tr>
```

Label tag removed and placeholder tag added.

I know we can do it by custom widget as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101258/how-do-i-add-a-placeholder-on-a-charfield-in-django). I want to just edit the existing model parameter and add these tags. Is it possible?

Comment: you can update widget from modelform: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878475/beginner-django-modelform-override-widget

Comment: I think its easier to render the fields manually.
Look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually
Is it essential you do it in model?