# Django Widget Tweaks help text as placeholder

Tags: django, django-widget-tweaks

Is there any way to render help text as placeholder in Django Widget Tweaks. New to django widget tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

This is that you need,  to set the placeholder attribute when creating the form. Refer to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44133785/4986502

In other cases when using  django-widget-tweaks,  template variables can be used as attribute values:

`{% render_field form.text placeholder=form.text.label %}`

Comment: I saw that but Is their any way rendering all field in single command like {{ form }}

Comment: Check out django-crispy-forms:  www.django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io