# Django Form Field Placeholder text using custom template tag

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I've looked everywhere for a simple way to add a `placeholder` text element to a Django Form input field.  There are several [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133562/django-add-placeholder-text-to-form-field)s that look to modify the model forms or use [add-ins](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/introduction/templates_placeholders.html).  I've pieced together several disparate examples to come up with the following...

This is my first custom template tag and before I add a lot of template changes I'd like to verify that this is correct:

**templatetags/[placeholder.py](https://gist.github.com/Miserlou/2025683)**

```
from django.template import Library
import re

register = Library()

def placeholder(value, token):
    value.field.widget.attrs["placeholder"] = token
    return value

register.filter(placeholder)
```

**templates/my_app/customer_form.html** (implementing Bootstrap)

```
<div class="container">
    <h5>Add a New Customer</h5>
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <table class="table table-borderless table-sm table-half">
            <tr><td>{{ form.customer | placeholder:'Customer Name' }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>{{ form.address1 | placeholder:'Address' }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>{{ form.address2 | placeholder:'Address' }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>{{ form.city | placeholder:'City' }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>{{ form.state | placeholder:'State' }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>{{ form.zip | placeholder:'Zip' }}</td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Add" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**Firefox**

[image]

A couple of things I noted:

a)  It looks like I can (i) use field tags in the custom tag and (ii) I can use plain text.

b)  No space between the custom tag name and the value.  If there is a space it throws `TemplateSyntaxError` that `placeholder requires 2 arguments, 1 provided`. (?)

My question is:  all the other examples on SO use `field.widget.attrs` in the Class `__init__` definitions of the Form (or elsewhere in the views/models) and not through a custom tag - is there a design issue with using a custom tag, is it just bad form or otherwise fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now used both the custom template tags and passing in pre-formatted context items.  I've come to the conclusion that there isn't an answer to this question.

If I have to write the code, it is easier to write it in the specific context, unless it is repeating, then either as a separate module or a template tag - either has about the same effort (for me).

Importable custom template tags do have the advantage if they are already written and can be imported - such as [{% load humanize %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/humanize/).