# Django form set placeholder in CharField instead of value

Tags: django, django-forms

Suppose I have a following simple form:

```
class UserForm(Form):
    first_name = CharField(label='First Name')
    last_name = CharField(label='Last Name')
```

And there is some custom validation.

When a user submitted invalid data, Django renders the form with invalid values inside the fields.

Is it possible to render empty CharFields but with placeholders that show the entered data?

Comment: How are you rendering the form in the template?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101258/how-do-i-add-a-placeholder-on-a-charfield-in-django) link here. It have nice way of doing what you asked.

Comment: @sumitsubedi, thank you. But how do I get the field value?

Comment: You can dynamically change the placeholder value of form while sending it from views.py as:         form.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = value